# Facebook Graph API requests take LONG? (file_get_contents)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using file_get_contents to retrieve stuff from the Facebook graph API (e.g: https://graph.facebook.com/me) and it takes like 5-10 seconds per request.

Any known issues on why this could be happening? When I ping the url from the browser it is really fast. Could it be a setting on my server?

Comment: Yes it could be something in your server, try setting up a local facebook application and try that call again...if you are satisfied with the response time, contact your server administrator.

Comment: My experience is 300ms in the best case. Commonly it takes 500ms. 5 seconds is a nightmare. I'm using Virpus hosting <-- it's not an ad, i don't have any relation with them... i'm from Ecuador :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. Use this cURL function :

```
function get_url($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    $tmp = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $tmp;
}
```

Does it work faster?

Comment: Hi, I'm going to try it again later tonight, but the last time I tried CURL was just as slow. I'll try copying/pasting your code.

Comment: Because of curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); it should be faster.

Comment: Hey this helped a bit! Took it down from 18 seconds to 5 seconds. 5 seconds still seems like a very long time for a single request though....

Comment: Then you have most likely a connectivity issue as on my computer/servers the FB graph requests take under 2 seconds.
As for the 5 seconds request .. did it went ok? Or the "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);" timeout came active?